# Is it possible to `split a hbox`?

Tags: boxes, plain-tex

When creating two columns or balancing it, we may use `\vsplit` to achieve this, but can we split a `\hbox` in TeX?

Compared with `\vsplit`, an example may be like this:

```
\setbox0=\hbox to 6in{ ... }
\setbox1=\hsplit0 to 3in
```

Maybe a method will be that we can put the contents of `\box0` into a `\vbox`, then the horizontal lists in `\box0` can be broken into lines. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically the method is as you said:

[image]

```
\setbox0=\hbox{one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven}
\setbox2=\vbox{%
\hsize=.5\wd0 
\noindent\unhbox0 \par 
\global\setbox3\lastbox
\unskip\unpenalty\unskip
\global\setbox1\lastbox
}

box1: \box1

box3: \box3


\bye
```

Comment: Yeah, David, maybe, this is the only method to do that, but, in my opinion :-)

Comment: Upvoted.  I am pretty sure, though, that LuaTeX would enable a "cleaner" approach.

Comment: @mbork surely you are not suggesting that lua code could beat the classic elegance of `\unskip\global\setbox1\lastbox` :-)

Comment: @TimLi if you only want to separate the items in a box then one could imagine other ways, and luatex gives you access to the horizontal list so you could reconstruct it, however if you want to split at exactly half distance and possibly break a word at that point, then you would have to invoke the hyphenation algorithm and so much of the line breaking machinery anyway.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I haven't used LuaTeX, only ConTeX for a week, but LuaTeX should be my choice in the future, It is cool to have access to the TeX kernel.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I am only a newbie in plain TeX. Could you tell me why we should use the last `\unskip` just before `\global\setbox1\lastbox`? After `global\setbox3\lastbox`, the boxes and glues have the form of `..\tenrm s  ..\tenrm i  ..\tenrm x  ..\glue(\rightskip) 0.0  .\penalty 300  .\glue(\baselineskip) 5.05556`. I know we should remove the interline glue and the penalty, so we can `\unskip` and `\unpenalty`, but I add `\unskip` just before `\global\setbox1\lastbox`, I get the same log file with not adding that.